# Export large set of numerical (complex) data

Tags: export

I want to export a large amount of numerical data. Every data point is a complex number. The data is supposed to be imported e.g. in Matlab or in Gnuplot. It is not important to have high-precision numbers (precision 4-5 should make the deal). File extension is also of no importance as long as it is readable by other common programs.

I want it in the format of `"Table"` when using the built-in `Export` function of Mathematica. An example of how the data should look like is the following code

```
data = RandomComplex[{1, I}, {10^4, 21}];
Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "testdata.txt"}], data, 
    "Table"]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

This takes already on my machine about 4 seconds, but I what I need is to export a matrix of dimensions up to 10^7x21. With `Export` this would take like ages. Is there a faster way to export such huge data sets?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Why not `Export["a.mat",data]`? This exports into Matlab's matrix format which is a binary format, widely spread, and quite efficient. A complex  matrix of size $10^7  \times 21$ is exported within 13 seconds on my machine.

Comment: Yes, this helps a lot I wasn't aware. Is it necessary to explicitly specify the format as "MAT" or will Mathematica automatically know the format when you give the extension .mat?

Comment: In general, Mathematica tries to tell the import/export format from the file extension. If it cannot tell, it will tell you so.